# Concatenate multiple records to one record with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I have a query like this:

```
Select * from
  (Select a, b, c from table1 where some condition) as Result1,
  (Select d, e from table2 where some another condition) as Result2
```

everything is OK until one of the nested selects returns nothing, then another select returns nothing too in finally select.

please tell me what is wrong with me?

Comment: replace your select statement with coalesce or is null function that will prevent you from throwing null value error

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal thanks for your comment, possible give me a sample, i'm new in posgresql, i did this with join in mysql

Comment: Use a [`full outer join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-table-expressions.html) between your two resultsets, rather than a Cartesian product.

Comment: @Phylogenesis i did this but it doesn't work first because i didn't know that ON condition join in postgresql is forced. finally it's working with this: Select * from
  (Select a, b, c from table1 where some condition) as Result1 FULL OUTER JOIN
  (Select d, e from table2 where some another condition) as Result2 ON 1 = 1

Comment: @Highlan As shown in my answer below, you can use an *always true* join condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, the following should work how you expect:

```
select
    *
from
    (select a, b, c from table1 where predicate1) Result1
full outer join
    (select d, e from table2 where predicate2) Result2 on
        1 = 1
```

Comment: that's exactly i did! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Try:

   ```
   Select (
     (Select a, b, c from table1 where some condition) as Result1,
     (Select d, e from table2 where some another condition) as Result
   )
   ```
2. Try an inner or self join
3. Post some result samples to get a better understanding of the issue.